# How to change an iPhone's microphone sampling rate

Tags: ios, swift, fft, accelerate-framework

I'm working on adding a feature to an existing app, to take audio input from the device microphone, convert it to frequency domain via an FFT and sends it to a coreML model. I'm using a standard `AVCaptureDevice`:

```
guard let microphone = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInMicrophone,
                                                   for: .audio,
                                                   position: .unspecified),
let microphoneInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: microphone) else {
                fatalError("Can't create microphone.")
}
```

The issue is, I require a custom sample rate to be defined for the microphone. Following Apple's documentation, `setPreferredSampleRate` [(link)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosession/1616523-setpreferredsamplerate) should be able to do that in a range between 8000-48000 Hz. However no matter which value I choose, the sample rate won't change, and no error is thrown:

```
print("Microphone sample rate: ", AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate)

do { var flag = try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setPreferredSampleRate(20000) }
catch { print("Unable to set microphone sampling rate!") }

print("Microphone sample rate: ", AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().sampleRate)
```

Output:

```
Microphone sample rate: 48000.0
Microphone sample rate: 48000.0
```

**How could I define the sampling rate for iOS devices?**

### EDIT:

Following the suggestion of using `AVAudioConverter` to resample microphone input, what's the most efficient way of doing this, considering I'm using `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` and the corresponding `captureOutput` method to collect raw audio input from the microphone:

```
extension AudioSpectrogram: AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    public func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput,
                              didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer,
                              from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList()
        var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?

        CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(
            sampleBuffer,
            bufferListSizeNeededOut: nil,
            bufferListOut: &audioBufferList,
            bufferListSize: MemoryLayout.stride(ofValue: audioBufferList),
            blockBufferAllocator: nil,
            blockBufferMemoryAllocator: nil,
            flags: kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment,
            blockBufferOut: &blockBuffer)

        guard let data = audioBufferList.mBuffers.mData else {
            return
        }

        if self.rawAudioData.count < self.sampleCount * 2 {
            let actualSampleCount = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer)

            let ptr = data.bindMemory(to: Int16.self, capacity: actualSampleCount)
            let buf = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: ptr, count: actualSampleCount)

            rawAudioData.append(contentsOf: Array(buf))
        }

        while self.rawAudioData.count >= self.sampleCount {
            let dataToProcess = Array(self.rawAudioData[0 ..< self.sampleCount])
            self.rawAudioData.removeFirst(self.hopCount)
            self.processData(values: dataToProcess)
        }
 }
```

Comment: "Preferred sample rate" is your preference. The device is not required to honor it. There is no way to definitively set the sample rate. You need to resample if you need some other rate. The sample rate is often determined by hardware, and there is no promise that it is adjustable. See AVAudioConverter for the built-in tools for performing conversions such as sample rate. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudioconverter

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I haven't used this functionality before, and I was wondering how it would interact with `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate`, as described in my edit

Comment: If you decide to resample the signal, vDSP provides a decimate function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/resampling_a_signal_with_decimation